# Detect lost filehandler in PHP when listening to logfiles

Tags: php, linux, logging

I am trying to build a small demon in PHP that analyzes the logfiles on a linux system.  (eg. follow the syslog).

I have managed to open the file via `fopen` and continuosly read it with `stream_get_line`. My problem starts when the monitored file is deleted and recreated (eg when rotating logs).  The program then does not read anything anymore, even if the file grew larger than previously.

Is there an elegant solution for this?  `stream_get_meta_data` does not help and using `tail -f` on the command line shows the same problem.

EDIT, added sample code
I tried to boil down the code to a minimum to illustrate what I am looking for

```
<?php
$break=FALSE;
$handle = fopen('./testlog.txt', 'r');
do {
    $line = stream_get_line($handle, 100, "\n");
    if(!empty($line)) {
        // do something
        echo $line;
    }
    while (feof($handle)) {
      sleep (5);
      $line = stream_get_line($handle, 100, "\n");
      if(!empty($line)) {
        // do something
        echo $line;
      }
      // a commented on php.net indicated it is possible
      // with tcp streams to distinguish empty and lost
      // does NOT work here  --> need somefunction($handle)
      if($line !== FALSE && $line ='') $break=TRUE;
    }
} while (!$break);
fclose($handle);
?>
```

Comment: Please add the code how you do this to your questions so that concrete suggestion for improvements can be made.

Comment: @hakre I added some code

Comment: Have you experimented with stream callbacks as well http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-notification-callback.php ? They might give you some hints.

Comment: Just to answer on this, problem seems solved now: It did not work for me, like this comment http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-notification-callback.php#99847 suggests.  I guess stream functions are very efficient to read anything at the expense of not monitoring other stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When log files are rotated, the original file is copied, then deleted, and a new file with the same name is created.  It may have the same name as the original file, but it has a different inode.  Inodes (dumbed down description follows) are like hidden incremental index numbers for your files.  You can change the name of a file, or move it, but it takes the inode with it.  Once that original log file is deleted, you can't re-open a file with the same name using the same file handler, because the inode has changed.  Your best bet is detect the failure, and attempt to open the new file.

Comment: Thanks Mrbinky, but basically that is my question, how do I detect that the file has been deleted?  stream_get_metadata does not change, the handle is still a stream object.

Comment: What is the array that stream_meta_data() returns?  You should be able to detect if the stream timed out while waiting for a read.  Try and shorten the value for stream_set_timeout() to something like 4 seconds. stream_meta_data() might only detect a timeout if you use something like read() instead of stream_get_line().

Comment: the timeout thing did not work, but your pointer towards using read did get me in the right direction. As far as I see, I can detect the change in fstat.  Anyway, the solution is to use the file related functions and not to rely on the stream functions.